# How can I convert .py into an .exe ? Pyinstaller does not work

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller


pyinstaller app.py
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bnfS.png)

so it says to me that pyinstaller could not found. But I have pyinstaller downloaded.
I do not know why?

Comment: Pyinstaller might not be on your PATH, depending on how you've set up your Python. Try `python -m pyinstaller` for an alternate invocation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `pyinstaller` to the PATH environment variable.

- While installing, check Add python to Path.
- First find the path of pyinstaller.exe, it's usually in Scripts directory of your python installation. Then copy file path and run `setx %PATH% "%PATH%;FULL PATH"` from Cmd.